# How one can prevent tree cycles in SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a group of extra changes to tree hierarchy in SQL:

```
Id, ParentId, Data
```

represented as list of tuples in random order (Id, ParentId):

```
(1,2)
(2,3)
(3,1)
```

It means that after those changes applied, Id marked rows will have corresponding ParentId.

So, to prevent cycles in table, I want to identify that this query is valid one beforehand and throw exception if it will create cycle or two.

All I found on SO is about checking whether table already contains cycles through cte, but not found any answer about preventing one to appear.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So you have this data in a table and want to validate that they are no loops before applying to the final/another table?

Comment: Yeap, I need to be sure that this change will not create any loop.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out myself. If one has better approach, please feel free to share it.

Holy grail:

```
create table #input (Id bigint,ParentId bigint)
insert into #input values (1,2),(2,3),(3,1);

with edges_cte (Id,ParentId) 
as
(
    select      Id,ParentId
    from        #input

    union all

    select      tt.Id,tt.ParentId
    from        edges_cte 
    join        %%%%TARGET_TABLE%%%% as tt on tt.ParentId = edges_cte.Id
    where       tt.Id NOT IN (select Id from #input)
)
select Id,ParentId into #edges from edges_cte;

with cycles as (
      select e.Id, e.ParentId, iscycle = 0
      from #edges e
      union all
      select cycles.Id, e.ParentId, (case when cycles.Id = e.ParentId then 1 else 0 end) as iscycle
      from cycles join
           #edges e
           on cycles.ParentId = e.Id
      where iscycle = 0
     )
select Id
from cycles
where iscycle = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a foreign key on the parentID field, you will never have a cycle during an insert, so, you can check your hierarchy from top to bottom and if you try to set the parent to an id that is already in that hierarchy it will return 1

```
    ALTER TABLE #input ADD FK_Parent FOREIGN KEY (ParentID) REFERENCES #input (id)
    GO
    CREATE FUNCTION fn_haveCycles (@id int, @newparent int)
    RETURNS bit
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @cycle BIT;
        WITH CTE AS(
            SELECT id, parentid from #input where id = @id
            UNION ALL
            SELECT i.id, i.parentid 
            FROM #input i
            JOIN cte
            ON i.parentid = cte.id 
        )
        SELECT @cycle = 1 
        FROM CTE 
        WHERE id = @newParentID

        RETURN ISNULL(@cycle, 0)
    END
    GO

    ALTER TABLE #Input 
    ADD CONSTRAINT ck_validatecycles 
    CHECK (dbo.fn_haveCycles(id, pareintid) = 0)
```